# How to get list of running HALs on Android device?

Tags: android, android-source, hal

I want to know whether specific HAL or HIDL interface is available on an Android device.

It better if there is a way to get the list of available binderized HAL services, passthrough HALs and their HIDL interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command.

**adb shell lshal**

lshal tool lists all binderized HALs and available passthrough HAL implementations (all -impl.so files).

Comment: Should this be working on older android versions like android 7.1 (API 25) ?